# OpenGLScreenSnapshot doesn't work in Mac OS X 10.7 - Lion

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-lion, glreadpixels

I've been writing a program based on the ScreenSnapshot example from apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenGLScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html
and after upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion my program stopped working. When I checked the example I realized it is not working either. 
For some reason glReadPixels function raises the GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION_EXT error (0x0506).

I have reinstalled developer's tools but no luck. Has anyone made any progress with this issue? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An updated version was posted a few days ago, see [this new sample code called ScreenSnapshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011158). There's now a dedicated fonction [CGDisplayCreateImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-SW14). There's even an accompanying [technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1741/_index.html).

So, a more général answer: follow Apple's document révisions regularly. (Sorry for extraneous accents over é's or fonctions... somehow Lion's spell checker wants to be in French mode.. grr...)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! That's very helpful. Actually I am interested in continuous screen capture, i.e. creating a movie of the screen. I found this Q/A: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011007  but I can't seem to find any sample code. Do you know if there is any?

Comment: That Q&A contains short snippets of the sample code, right? You can plug them in to a Cocoa template, and off you go.

Comment: CGDisplayCreateImage aside, the fact that glReadPixels is no longer working means Apple has a bug in their driver right?